# Generating a diagram of labels with connecting lines

Tags: diagrams

I need to generate a diagram showing relationships between points. I can convert my data into a simple syntax, such as this below (other forms of syntax is okay too):

```
A (B, C) % A is connected to B and C
C (A, D, E, F) % C is connected to A, D, E, and F
```

The resulting information should be converted into some kind of diagram, such as this:

```
A------------------------B
 \                      /
  C-----D              /
 / \     \            /
E---F     G          /
 \   \   / \        /
  \   H /   I      /
   \   /   /|     /
    \ /   / |    /
     J---K--L---M
    / \ /    \ /        N   O      P   Q
```

- The points will contain words, e.g.

  "ocean" ("current", "tidal wave")
- These points should never be placed on top of other points, otherwise, it would be difficult to read them.
- There are no arrows at the ends of the lines.
- There are no labels at the mid-points of the lines.

Are there any tools which can generate such a diagram?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) and [dot2tex](http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/). The `dot` program in the `graphviz` suite should let you define the relationships and `dot2tex` should convert it to Tikz for you. You can turn the TikZ into `pdf` with LaTeX.

I haven't used `dot2tex` but I have used `dot`: it's easy to use.

Answer (score 5):

I enter the coordinates line after line, I think it's not too difficult.
If some words are too long, you can modify the value of `x`.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

% style
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {draw, shape=rectangle}}
\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style   = {dashed,color  = orange}}  

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.25cm,y=-2cm]
% vertex
\foreach \xv/\yv/\v/\Lv in {%
 0/0/A/Word 1, 10/0/B/Word 2,
 1/1/C/Word 3, 5/1/D/Word 4,
 0/2/E/Word 5, 2/2/F/Word 6, 6/2/G/Word 7,
 3/3/H/Word 8, 7/3/I/Word 9,
 2/5/J/Word 10, 4/5/K/Word 11, 6/5/L/Word 12, 8/5/M/Word 13,
 1/6/N/Word 14, 3/6/O/Word 15, 7/6/P/Word 16, 9/6/Q/Word 17}%
  {\Vertex[x=\xv,y=\yv,L=\Lv]{\v}}
% edges
\Edges(I,K,O,J,E,C,D,G,I,L,P,M,B,A,C,F,H) 
\Edges(N,J,K,L,M,Q) \Edges(G,J) \Edges(E,F)   

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]